# Using null-coalescing with a property or call method

Tags: c#, operators

It is possible to use the [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operation in a situation such this:

```
string str = collection["NoRepeate"] ?? null; // Will not compile 
                          //because collection["NoRepeate"] is object
```

The problem here is that it is not possible to assign `collection["NoRepeate"]` which is `object` to `str` and `collection["NoRepeate"].ToString()` throws exception when its value is null.

I'm using now conditional operator [`?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
str = collection["NoRepeate"].HasValue ? collection["NoRepeate"].ToString() : null
```

But the problem is in repeating the constant string.

Comment: For the 1st statement: If `collection["NoRepeate"]` is non-null then the `?? null` part is ignored. If it is null then it already is `null`, so the `?? null` is redundant.

Comment: I agree with KennyTM.  It makes no sense to put 'null' in the null coalescing operator.  That operator's purpose is to find the first non null value.  I would think just string str = collection["NoRepeate"]; would be what you want.

Comment: `collection["NoRepeate"]` is object and I've written that this will not compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you that it is a bit vexing that this cannot be done in a single statement. The null coalescing operator does not help here.

The shortest I am aware of requires two statements.

```
object obj = collection["NoRepeate"];
string str = obj == null ? null : obj.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
string str = (string) collection["NoRepeate"] ?? null;
```

This assumes the object is actually a string though. If it's not, you're going to get a run time error. The other solutions are more robust.

There is no real point in getting this to be as short as possible though. You should make your code readable, not "How short can I write this?"

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
var field = "NoRepeate";

var str = collection[field].HasValue ? collection[field].ToString() : null;
```

Of course, if you don't have [primitive obsessions](http://agile.dzone.com/articles/primitive-obsession) you can add a method to the collection class to do this this. Else you'll probably have to stick with an extension method.

Comment: Doing this is not ideal is it requires two trips into the dictionary which can be expensive.

Comment: I thought that was why you used a dictionary - key-based lookups are meant to be cheap

Comment: They are, but they're not free.  A string has to calculate its hashcode each time, then the dictionary has to pick the right bucket, then it walks through that bucket comparing each string until it finds a match.  It's faster than a brute-force search but not magic.

Answer (score 1):

Is the object returned from the collection actually a `Nullable<object>`? Otherwise, you probably want to explicitly check for null:

```
var item = collection["NoRepeate"];
string str = (item == null) ? null : item.ToString();
```

Comment: What is the difference between `item == null` and `!item.HasValue` ?

Comment: A Nullable<object> isnt possible since Nullable has the constraint that T be a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's very possible, if the returned value is null. If the returned value is "" then no. I use it all the time for null values to assign a default.

Comment: Also note not everything can be nullable (altho `object` should be able to be null)